# Delete text after #example iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

How can I erase a part of **NSString** or **NSArray** after a word, for example *#gallery-1* or after two "skip lines" ? And is it possible to delete a sentence that appears every time ?

I would like to erase all the text after #gallery-1 or after 2 skip lines in this NSString (or NSArray) and erase "CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM" :

```
3rd March
Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh.

High tide: 1703 3.6m     CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM
Low Tide: 1041 0.8m
3 day forecast to March 5th
Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind.


            #gallery-1 {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
                float: left;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 50%;
            }
            #gallery-1 img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */








 
 Wind Charts
         Wind Guru       XC Weather       Buoy Weather
Swell Charts
                                     Magic Seaweed      MSM WAM          Marine Institute
Pressure, Weather, Tides
                      BBC Pressure      Met Eireann      Irish Tide Tables
```

I would like to obtain :

```
3rd March
    Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh.

    High tide: 1703 3.6m     CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM
    Low Tide: 1041 0.8m
    3 day forecast to March 5th
    Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `NSString` documentation? There is a method `substringToIndex:` that you can combine with `rangeOfString:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straightforward. Just use an instance methods from NSString class.

REMOVE OCCURENCES

```
NSString *originalString = @"#gallery-1 {margin: auto;}#gallery-1 .gallery-item {float: left;margin-top: 10px;text-align: center;width: 50%;}";

NSString *processedString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#gallery-1" withString:@""];
```

Obviously, the original string can contain much longer string with multiple occurrences. So if it contains more of them, all occurrences will be replaced for you in a one-liner method. It couldn't be easier really.

SPLIT

```
NSString *originalString = @"3rd March Swell is 5 foot and cross shore, bitter in the cold wind. Maybe streedagh.     High tide: 1703 3.6m     CLICK HER FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM  Low Tide: 1041 0.8m    3 day forecast to March 5th    Good swell all weekend but the winds are changing. Keep in an eye for gaps in the wind.#gallery-1 {margin: auto;}#gallery-1 .gallery-item {float: left;margin-top: 10px;text-align: center;width: 50%;}";

NSString *processedString = [[originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#gallery"] firstObject];
```

The string here is separated into a number of components (each being a string, basically the text is cut into pieces) and the "delimiter" is anything that is put as parameter. All components are inside an NSArray and we really need only the first one.

Comment: That erase just #gallery-1, but not all the text behind #gallery-1 :/ But that will help me to delete "CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM"

Comment: You can put anything into that replacement string - @#gallery-1    ".  So if you need to remove spaces...put spaces there..
@""

Comment: And if you need to remove other text ..just have another line with @"WEBCAM"....or other lines...certainly the whole job is a few lines..

Comment: Yeah but look at my data after #gallery-1... there's a lot !

Comment: What is a lot? a 100 words...or a million? Don't worry the system can handle that in a few milliseconds.

Comment: Ok I will update..you want to SPLIT the string..no erase words from it.

Comment: That's right, but if the website change content, that will handle the wrong data too ...

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm, a few ways off the top of my head, where input is the above string.

This will separate the components of the string by two "skipped lines" as you put it.

```
let finalComponents = input.componentsSeperatedByString("\n\n")
let wantedInfo = finalComponents[0] as String
```

To get rid of "CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM":

```
let unwanted = "CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM"
let finalString = wantedInfo.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(unwanted, replacement:"")
```

Comment: Oh well, Thank you very much for the reply, but I work on Objective-C :(